# Which is better in these two jQuery snippets

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery DOM element `node`, and I want to search few elements from `node`. I have two solutions here

```
 1 : node.find('a,b,c,d,e').each(..)
 2 : node.find('a')...., node.find('b')....
 3 : node = jQuery([]).pushStack( node.find('a,b,c,d,e') ) etc..
```

Which one is preferable with large DOM element. I am looking for only speed.

Comment: Better in terms of what? Memory? Speed? Style? Something else?

Comment: none of them.......`:p`

Comment: @FelixKling Speed, not memory or readability or style...

Comment: In that case I recommend to run some http://jsperf.com/ tests.

Comment: In case of speed, don't use jQuery. `;)`

Comment: @Fabrício Matté You are absolutely correct, but I don't have other option now..

Comment: What I meant is, you already have the overhead of loading the jQuery file + processing its init, all your 3 snippets will have nothing but a minimum difference in performance as the heaviest part is surely the DOM queries they perform. I'd personally choose 1 as that would perform a single DOM query instead of many queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little broad but here's my analysis of the code posted.

Option 3 is nothing but a more redundant option 1: `$.fn.find` already returns a jQuery object, there is no need to decompose it and add its elements to yet another jQuery object.

Option 2 is fine when you're doing something completely different with each element:

```
node
  .find('a').doThis().end()
  .find('b').doThat();
```

Note that `.end()` is most likely slower than using `node.find()` again - a variable lookup is usually faster a function call, but then we're talking about microseconds.

I'd consider option 1 the best performance-wise, as it will perform only a single DOM query.

Note that if you're applying simple methods without element-specific logic, you don't need `.each()`, so then you have an option 4:

```
 node.find('a,b,c,d,e').doSomething();
```

That is, jQuery does implicit iteration applying `doSomething` to each matched element.

All of these will have unnoticeable performance difference unless applied inside a huge loop. [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) is the tool to run performance tests, but note that modern JS engines such as V8 do a quite good job optimizing repetitive behavior.

Also, remember *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*. Deal with performance issues as they become apparent. Don't sacrifice readability for microseconds. You can use optimization tools such as [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) before deploying to gain some micro/milliseconds performance.